# Android Studio - Program type Already Present

Tags: android, gradle, circular-dependency, arcore, conflicting-libraries

After adding ARCore dependencies to my existing android app.I get

> Program type already present: com.google.flatbuffers.Constants

error,while running the APK

I have tried to exclude the group from ARCORE,but it didnt help

FYI,here's my gradle (app)

```html
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.9'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'saschpe.android:customtabs:1.1.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.leinardi:FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:e5366623b7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
//    //ARCORE SDK
    implementation ('com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.flatbuffers'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.5.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.flatbuffers'
    }
    //ARCORE-LOCATION
    implementation ('com.github.appoly:ARCore-Location:1.1.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.flatbuffers'
    }
}
```

this is my dependency graph

```html
+--- io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.2.0
|    \--- io.objectbox:objectbox-java:2.2.0
|         +--- io.objectbox:objectbox-java-api:2.2.0
|         +--- org.greenrobot:essentials:3.0.0-RC1
|         +--- com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.9.0
|         \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|         |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:16.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
+--- com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3
+--- com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.9
+--- com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0
|    +--- com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.3
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3
|    |    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 (*)
|    |    |    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.1
|    |    |    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.2
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.0.2 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.1
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.3
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.4
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.6.4
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.3 (*)
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.4
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.4
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.10
|         \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.4
+--- saschpe.android:customtabs:1.1.2
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.4.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4
+--- com.github.leinardi:FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:e5366623b7
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.13
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.13
|    |    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 3.0.2
|    |    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 3.0.2
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:17.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:16.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:16.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1
|    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.12.0
|    |    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.12.0] -> 1.12.0
|    |    |    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-context:1.12.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0 -> 3.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:0.11.0
|    |    |    |    \--- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics:0.11.0
|    |    |    |         \--- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:0.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0 -> 2.7.5
|    |    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0 -> 1.14.0
|    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0 -> 1.14.0
|    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.12.0
|    |    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-core:1.12.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0
|    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.12.0
|    |    |    \--- io.grpc:grpc-core:1.12.0 (*)
|    |    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2
|    |    |    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9 -> 2.1.14
|    |    |         \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2
|    |    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.14 (*)
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5 (*)
|    \--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:16.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-abt:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3 (*)
+--- com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.5.0
|    +--- com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.5.0
|    |    +--- com.google.ar.sceneform:rendering:1.5.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.ar:core:1.5.0
|    |    +--- com.google.ar.sceneform:sceneform-base:1.5.0
|    |    \--- com.google.ar.sceneform:filament-android:1.5.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.github.appoly:ARCore-Location:1.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 16.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.0.0 -> 1.5.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.0.0 -> 1.5.0 (*)
```

no dependency other than object box is using flat buffers,then how could it get a conflict with others?

please,someone could help?

Comment: Execute `./gradlew app:dependencies` on a terminal to check which other packages import it. Then apply exclude to all `implementation`s that do.

Comment: dear,i have checked this..only object box is depending on flatbuffers...when i uncomment object box and check the dependency graph again,i see none of my dependencies are depending on flatbuffers...so only objectbox is the one using it...although when i add dependencies for arcore lib's it sync with gradle but when i run the app..i get this error.. what could be the problem

Comment: @Clinkz any updates,please check my dependency graph...really stuck with this